# Replacing color.xml and images during build

Tags: android, xml, maven, maven-plugin

I use Maven to build Android application. I had to build different apps with same code base. But each contains a different theme (button and page colors from `color.xml` and colored icons from the drawable folder). I replace these manually every time before releasing each app.

Can you suggest an easy way to do this with tools? Or is it possible to replace the `color.xml` and images through Maven by providing the desired directory path?

I have searched throughout the internet but I am not able to find answers to this particular problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [maven profiles](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html) and [resource plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/)

You need to define the profiles in your `pom.xml`:

```
</profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>variantA</id>
        <build>
            <!-- custom conf for variant A -->
        </build>
    </profile>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>variantB</id>
        <build>
            <!-- custom conf for variant B -->
        </build>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Then invoque your build with the desired profile:

```
mvn clean install -P variantB
```

Also with the Resource plugin you can overwrite the entire color.xml file (on this example creating the `color.xml` file in the folder `src/templates/resVariantA`):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>initialize</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>copy-resources</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/res</outputDirectory>
                <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                <resources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${project.basedir}/src/templates/resVariantA</directory>
                        <targetPath>${project.basedir}/res</targetPath>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                     </resource>
                 </resources>
             </configuration>
         </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Hope it helps.